# /home/webapp: No such file or directory elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, ruby, elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy my ruby app on aws using elastic beanstalk. Following error occur.
[pass log](https://pastebin.com/MmzLRsQJ)

```
App 20278 stdout: intializing git
App 20278 stderr: error: could not lock config file /home/webapp/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
App 20278 stderr: sh: line 0: cd: /home/webapp: No such file or directory
```

[eb log](https://pastebin.com/mVn1iCWi)

log also says

```
Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <webapp@ip-172-31-28-185.us-east-2.compute.internal>) not allowed
```

[Puma.log](https://pastebin.com/0gxu89r1)
[eb.activity.log](https://pastebin.com/w63YER55)
Why it is saying "/home/webapp: No such file or directory"

Please tell me how to fix this